# addClass to parent not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There's an `a` inside the `li` elements. I want to add the `current` class  to the related `li` when the user clicks on the `a`. However, I am not sure how it can be done.

```js
$(".nav-link").on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('current');
})
```

```css
.nav-item.current {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item current">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Contact</div>
</div>
```

I tried to use toggle but it will mess up when I click the a link again. Please help me. Thank you.

codepen - https://codepen.io/rae0724/pen/pZNQMK

For some reasons, if i need the function to detect if `.nav-link` has class `.active`, then just add on the `current` class to parent? any ways I can make this happen?

Comment: what you are describing that you want, already works. If you want to remove a `current` class from an element when clicking on another link, then that's a different question alltogether

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the updated function

```
   $(".nav-link").on('click', function(e) {
      $(".current").removeClass('current');
      $(this).parent().addClass('current');
    })
```

I added  `$(".current").removeClass('current');` line.
You need to remove the current class from all the elements first, then add it again on the required element.

```js
$(".nav-link").on('click', function(e) {
  $(".current").removeClass('current');
  $(this).parent().addClass('current');
})
```

```css
.nav-item.current {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item current">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Contact</div>
</div>
```

**Updated Answer**(based on comments)

```
 $(".nav-link").on('click', function(e) {
      $(".current").removeClass('current');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".active").parent().addClass('current');
      }, 0);

    })
```

```js
$(".nav-link").on('click', function(e) {
  $(".current").removeClass('current');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".active").parent().addClass('current');
  }, 0);

})
```

```css
.nav-item.current {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item current">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Contact</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Comment: Please add some explanation!

Comment: Was doing that only @both of the commentors! :) Seems like you were eyeing for a mistake :p No hard feelings. I would have said the same thing too though :)

Comment: thank you very much but, for some reasons, what if i need the function to detect if .nav-link has class ".active", then just add on the "current" class to parent? is it doable?

Comment: @demoncoder the answer is right in your question :) . `$(this).hasClass('active') &&  $(this).parent().addClass('current') `

Comment: See my updated answer, you need a settimeout, because bootstrap is also changing the active classes , and by the time you check for the active class on element, it is not actually present on the element in which it is supposed to be, so without the settimeout, your code wont work.

Comment: now i understand. thanks! it's exactly what i want. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class from all siblings and add to the active link, 
use `$(this).parent().addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');` to achieve it, please check the working example below.

```js
$(".nav-link").on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
})
```

```css
.nav-item.current {
  width: 300px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item current">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Contact</div>
</div>
```